# Consolidate rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to cut down on rows a report has. There are 2 assets that return on this query but I want them to show up on one row.

Basically if dc.name LIKE '%CT/PT%' then I want it to be same row as the asset. The SP.SVC_PT_ID is the common field to join them.

There will be times when there is no dc.name LIKE '%CT/PT%' however I still want the DV.MFG_SERIAL_NUM to populated just with a Null to the right.

[image]

```
Select SP.SVC_PT_ID, SP.DEVICE_ID, DV.MFG_SERIAL_NUM, dc.name, 
substr(dc.name,26) 
From EIP.SVC_PT_DEVICE_REL SP,
 eip.device_class dc,
 EIP.DEVICE DV
Where SP.EFF_START_TIME < To_date('20170930', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1
and SP.EFF_END_TIME is null
and dc.id = DV.device_class_id
and DV.ID = SP.device_id
ORDER BY SP.SVC_PT_ID, DV.MFG_SERIAL_NUM;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying; test case would certainly help. You said that query you posted returns two rows (only if we saw which ones ...) but you want them to be displayed as the image you attached to the message.

Generally speaking, you can do that using an aggregate function (such as MAX) on certain column(s), along with the GROUP BY clause that contains the rest of them.

Just for example:

```
select svc_pt_id, max(ctpt_name) ctpt_name, sum(ctpt_multipler) ctpt_multipler
from ...
group by svc_pt_id
```

As I said: a test case would help people who'd want to answer the question. True - someone might have understood it far better than I did and will provide assistance nevertheless.

EDIT: after you posted sample data (which, by the way, don't match screenshot you posted previously), maybe something like this might do the job: use analytic function to check whether name contains CT/PT; if so, take its data. Otherwise, display both rows.

```
SQL> with test as (
  2    select 14 svc_pt_id, 446733 device_id, 'Generic Electric' name from dual union
  3    select 14, 456517, 'Generic CT/PT, Multiplier' from dual
  4  ),
  5  podaci as
  6  (select svc_pt_id, device_id, name,
  7     rank() over (partition by svc_pt_id
  8                  order by  case when instr(name, 'CT/PT') > 1 then 1
  9                                 else 2
 10                            end) rnk
 11   from test
 12  )
 13  select svc_pt_id, device_id, name
 14  from podaci
 15  where rnk = 1;

 SVC_PT_ID  DEVICE_ID NAME
---------- ---------- -------------------------
        14     456517 Generic CT/PT, Multiplier

SQL>
```

My TEST table (created by WITH factoring clause) would be the result of your current query.